# Winforms Component Designer Integration

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, custom-component

I want to create a winform component that contains a collection of other elements, similar to TabControl (contains TabPage) or ListView (Contains columns).

The subItems have a Name property, and I want that name to be used in the generated code to access the subitems. Like in TabControl, I can name each tabpage using the editor.

Finally I want the subItems to be localized. Once again, like in TabControl, where I can localize each TabPage's text using the editor.

The problems I have is
1) how to get the Name property being used for code generation?
2) how to get the sub items properly localized?

Any good article to read?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. The subitems must inherit from Component as well.